# Use content-disposition attachment in RemoteServiceServlet

Tags: java, gwt, httprequest, content-disposition

I have an application that successfully receives an input string from the user, processes it on server-side, and displays the result on a webpage. I had implemented it as a RemoteServiceServlet, because this way I can handle all the website gadgets easily.

Nevertheless I have decided to, instead of displaying the result on a webpage, use the "content-disposition attachment" possibilities so that the user can download the processed string in a txt file.

Is there a way to do this without changing the whole application from RemoteServiceServlet to HttpServlet?

Below my code. Thanks a million.

**ProjectServiceImpl.java**

```
public class ProjectServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ProjectService 
{
    public String project(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    {
        String output = processString(input);
        // Below something I tried to do, but it does not work at all
        try {
            HttpServletResponse resp = getThreadLocalResponse();
        resp.reset();
        resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        resp.setContentLength(10);
        resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.txt\"");
        ServletOutputStream op = resp.getOutputStream();
        op.write(convertToByteArray(output),0,10);
        op.flush();
        op.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

**ProjectService.java**

```
public interface ProjectService extends RemoteService {
    String project(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**ProjectServiceAsync.java**

```
public interface ProjectServiceAsync {
    void project(String input, AsyncCallback<String> callback)
            throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**MyProject.java: Client side**

```
[...]
projectService.project(originalString, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
    [...]
    public void onSuccess(final String result) 
    {
        [...] // Or perhaps should I create here in client-side the txt file with "result"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing to another servlet, consider using one of each - the XmlHttpRequest that RPC uses as transport can't be used to download a file, but is still very handy for almost all of your requests to the server. XHRs are only good for communicating from javascript to the server, and can't be used for downloads (or other things, such as opening new windows with content).

Consider making another servlet, and having the RPC call return a string, a url for that other servlet (plus probably some other parameters to indicate what should be downloaded).